# I want a pop up box that will tell someone which outside website they are being directed to that will hold for 15 seconds before moving to new webpage

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, popup

I currently have the code to set up with an innerHTML message. I want to turn that into a pop up that will show for 15 seconds and then open the window to the correct website.  There are 6 different innerHTML messages that need to be seen depending on which website they are being directed to.
I also want it to work on mobile devices.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Leaving the Treatment Center </title>
<style>
    margin:auto;
    font-family:verdana;
</style>
    <center><label for="Zipcode">Zip Code:</label></center>
    <center><input type="text" id="Zipcode" name="Zipcode"></center>
    <p id="Zipcode_text"></p>
    <br>
    <center><button onclick="myFunction()">Find My Local Intergroup</button></center>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var a = document.getElementById("Zipcode").value;
            if (a == "41310") {
                document.getElementById("Zipcode_text").innerHTML = "Thank you. You will be directed to the Bluegrass Intergroup's Website";
                // <a href="http://www.bluegrassintergroup.org/"> Bluegrass Intergroup's Website</a>;
                window.open("http://www.bluegrassintergroup.org/", 'newwindow')
       } 
       else if (a == "42101") {
                document.getElementById("Zipcode_text").innerHTML = "Thank you. You will be directed to the Bowling Green Intergroup's Webpage";
                // <a href=" http://bowlinggreenaa.org/">Bowling Green Intergroup's Webpage</a>;
                window.open(" http://bowlinggreenaa.org/", 'newwindow')
            }
        else if (a == "42070") {
                document.getElementById("Zipcode_text").innerHTML = "Thank you. You will be directed to the Western Kentucky Intergroup's Website";
                // <a href="https://wkintergroup.org/"> The Western Kentucky Intergroup's Website</a>;
                window.open("https://wkintergroup.org/", 'newwindow')
            }
        else if (a == "40202") {
                document.getElementById("Zipcode_text").innerHTML = "Thank you. You will be directed to the Greater Louisville Intergroup's Website";
                // <a href="https://www.loukyaa.org/"> Greater Louisville Intergroup's Website</a>;
                window.open("https://www.loukyaa.org/", 'newwindow')
        }
        else if (a == "41063") {
                document.getElementById("Zipcode_text").innerHTML = "Thank you. You will be directed to the Northern Kentucky Intergroup's Website";
                // <a href="https://www.nkyaa.info/"> The Northern Kentucky Intergroup's Website</a>;
                window.open("https://www.nkyaa.info/", 'newwindow')
        }
        else if (a == "42343") {
                document.getElementById("Zipcode_text").innerHTML = "Thank you. You will be directed to the Owensboro-Yellowbanks Intergroup's Website";
                // <a href="https://www.area26.net/wp/owensboro-yellowbanks-central-office/"> The Owensboro-Yellowbanks Intergroup's Website</a>;
                window.open("https://www.area26.net/wp/owensboro-yellowbanks-central-office/", 'newwindow')
        }
       else {
                document.getElementById("Zipcode_text").innerHTML = "I'm sorry but we have not found a local Intergroup that covers that area. Please feel free to reach out to another intergroup to help connect to Alcoholics Anonymous in Kentucky, Southern Indiana and Ohio.";
                // <a href="https://www.area26.net/wp/local-intergroups/"> Area 26 Find A Meeting Page</a>;
                window.open("https://www.area26.net/wp/local-intergroups/", 'newwindow')
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Leaving the Treatment Center </title>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: auto;
      font-family: verdana;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <center><label for="Zipcode">Zip Code:</label></center>
  <center><input type="text" id="Zipcode" name="Zipcode"></center>
  <p id="Zipcode_text"></p>
  <br>
  <center><button onclick="myFunction()">Find My Local Intergroup</button></center>
  <script defer>
    function myFunction() {
      var a = document.getElementById("Zipcode").value;
      if (a == "41310") {
        document.getElementById("Zipcode_text").innerHTML = "Thank you. You will be directed to the Bluegrass Intergroup's Website";
        // <a href="http://www.bluegrassintergroup.org/"> Bluegrass Intergroup's Website</a>;
        setTimeout(function() {
          window.open("http://www.bluegrassintergroup.org/", 'newwindow')
        }, 15000);
      } else if (a == "42101") {
        document.getElementById("Zipcode_text").innerHTML = "Thank you. You will be directed to the Bowling Green Intergroup's Webpage";
        // <a href=" http://bowlinggreenaa.org/">Bowling Green Intergroup's Webpage</a>;
        setTimeout(function() {
          window.open(" http://bowlinggreenaa.org/", 'newwindow')
        }, 15000);
      } else if (a == "42070") {
        document.getElementById("Zipcode_text").innerHTML = "Thank you. You will be directed to the Western Kentucky Intergroup's Website";
        // <a href="https://wkintergroup.org/"> The Western Kentucky Intergroup's Website</a>;
        setTimeout(function() {
          window.open("https://wkintergroup.org/", 'newwindow')
        }, 15000);
      } else if (a == "40202") {
        document.getElementById("Zipcode_text").innerHTML = "Thank you. You will be directed to the Greater Louisville Intergroup's Website";
        // <a href="https://www.loukyaa.org/"> Greater Louisville Intergroup's Website</a>;
        setTimeout(function() {
          window.open("https://www.loukyaa.org/", 'newwindow')
        }, 15000);
      } else if (a == "41063") {
        document.getElementById("Zipcode_text").innerHTML = "Thank you. You will be directed to the Northern Kentucky Intergroup's Website";
        // <a href="https://www.nkyaa.info/"> The Northern Kentucky Intergroup's Website</a>;
        setTimeout(function() {
          window.open("https://www.nkyaa.info/", 'newwindow')
        }, 15000);
      } else if (a == "42343") {
        document.getElementById("Zipcode_text").innerHTML = "Thank you. You will be directed to the Owensboro-Yellowbanks Intergroup's Website";
        // <a href="https://www.area26.net/wp/owensboro-yellowbanks-central-office/"> The Owensboro-Yellowbanks Intergroup's Website</a>;
        setTimeout(function() {
          window.open("https://www.area26.net/wp/owensboro-yellowbanks-central-office/", 'newwindow')
        }, 15000);
      } else {
        document.getElementById("Zipcode_text").innerHTML = "I'm sorry but we have not found a local Intergroup that covers that area. Please feel free to reach out to another intergroup to help connect to Alcoholics Anonymous in Kentucky, Southern Indiana and Ohio.";
        // <a href="https://www.area26.net/wp/local-intergroups/"> Area 26 Find A Meeting Page</a>;
        setTimeout(function() {
          window.open("https://www.area26.net/wp/local-intergroups/", 'newwindow')
        }, 15000);
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**I just added a setTimeout function that waits 15000 milliseconds (15s) and then initiates the function to open the site that you prompted in your code.** I also cleaned up any mishaps I thought could have done some fixes like in the css, deferring the script tag, and remove of anything unnecessary. Also this does work on mobile just as a side note. I hope this helps :)

**P.S.** - Stackoverflow won't allow you to open a window so you have to run this locally ( Preferably on a live server / code editor extensions / HTML code compiler )